# Is my book too much like Harry Potter? I feel like it's close to it and everyone will think I'm copying it

Tags: fiction, plagiarism

(I'm summarizing)
My book is about 2 girls who find a secret passageway and find a room that they have to figure out which "substance" will get them through the water wall (like when Hermione had to figure out how to get Harry to be able to go through the door of fire). Then they meet twin boys and become friends with them (I feel like it's similar to the Weasley twins even though they are blonde) one twin is smarter than the other and the other is funnier than the other. The one that's funnier is a werewolf (like Lupin) and then accidentally turns a girl into a werewolf. That's all I have so far. One girl is African American that speaks French (like some people say Sirius does but I'm not sure if it's true) with her family and the other girl has red hair (like the Weasleys)

Comment: *Wow.* I can't believe there is another "is my story copying Harry Potter" question being asked. We have so, so so, many of them. https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=similar+to+harry+potter

Comment: @Nai45 I know, it's stressing me out though. My book isn't one that's already been asked about.

Comment: Here's my answer to just one possible duplicate question. It's all been done before, but make it your own and unique. https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/54226/same-plot-but-different-story-is-it-plagiarizing/54227#54227

Comment: @DWKraus thank you so much :)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! As has been noted already, this is a question we receive quite often. Since you've indicated that DWKraus' answer on the linked question is helpful to you, I'm going to go ahead and mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @CadenceVanAlst It shouldn't stress you out. Looking at your summary, I doubt anyone would ever call it a copy off. You are completely fine! ;)

Comment: I think it's time to create a new question tag: #ismybooktoomuchlikeharrypotter